# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object not found in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got an error for the code below which I could not understand:
**Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'avg_Depression' not found**
What could be the reason?

```
 data %>%
      group_by(Group, Time) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(avg_Depression = mean(Depression),
                      se_Depression = sd(Depression)/sqrt(n())) %>%
      ggplot(data = data, 
           mapping = aes(x = Rumination, 
                         y = Depression,
                         color = Time,
                         ymin = avg_Depression - se_Depression,
                         ymax = avg_Depression + se_Depression)) +
                         geom_pointrange(size = 1.2, alpha = .6, 
                         position = position_dodge(width = .1)) +
           geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, se=F)+
           facet_wrap(~Group)+
           theme_bw() +
           theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Can you run this and tell us what it says `colnames(data)`. I suspect the column name `avg_Depression` isn't quite correct.

Comment: The issue is probably that you pipe your data into `ggplot(..)` while also setting the data argument via `data = data`. Try with `... %>% ggplot(mapping = ...)`, i.e. remove `data = data`.

Comment: As it stands, this question is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). Please provide usable, unambiguous data.

Answer (score 1):

stefan's note is exactly right.

When you start, `data` represents your data in a named object. As soon as R executes through `%>% group_by(...)`, the values and structure of the object is ephemeral, not existing in a named object. Just like in `a <- 5 ; a + 9`, the `14` is never assigned to anything. This is often either later explicitly stored into a new object

```r
newdata <- data %>%
  group_by(...) %>%
  summarize(...)
## or less-commonly-seen right-hand assignment
data %>%
  group_by(...) %>%
  summarize(...) -> newdata
```

or discarded, solely for the side-effect, as you are intending to do here:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(...) %>%
  summarize(...) %>%
  ggplot(...) + geom_point() + ...
```

In your case, you group and then summarize the data, adding `avg_Depression`, and then assign `data=data` referring to the *original* contents of the object named `data`. There are two problems with this:

1. Your new summarized data is not included here. In fact, `ggplot(.)` does not see summarized data, it sees the raw data.
2. You don't explicitly assign where the piped data is going. Often you may see people code in the `.` placeholder for explicit/self-documenting `%>%`-pipe-flow, such as

   ```r
   mylm <- mydata %>%
     group_by(...) %>%
     summarize(...) %>%
     lm(A ~ B + C, data = .)
   ```

   By default, the `%>%` pipe operator will place the data from the previous step (LHS) into the first argument of the next step (RHS). However, if the RHS expression includes the `.` placeholder, then the data is assigned to that argument instead. (This does not work the same as the native-R `|>` pipe, btw, not a factor here.)

   Because you do not include the explicit `.` placeholder, though, this is what is actually happening:

   ```r
    data %>%
         group_by(Group, Time) %>%
         dplyr::summarise(avg_Depression = mean(Depression),
                         se_Depression = sd(Depression)/sqrt(n())) %>%
         ggplot(., data = data, 
              mapping = aes(...)) + ...
   ```

   which means that the piped data is falling with `ggplot`'s `...` (catch-all) argument. You don't hear about this because from `?ggplot2::ggplot`:

   ````
    ```
    Arguments:
        data: Default dataset to use for plot. If not already a data.frame,
              will be converted to one by 'fortify()'. If not specified,
              must be supplied in each layer added to the plot.
     mapping: Default list of aesthetic mappings to use for plot. If not
              specified, must be supplied in each layer added to the plot.
         ...: Other arguments passed on to methods. Not currently used.
    ```
   ````

   the `...` is not currently used.

Bottom line, change your `data=data` to `data=.` (or just remove `data=data` completely), and it should work:

```r
 data %>%
      group_by(Group, Time) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(avg_Depression = mean(Depression),
                      se_Depression = sd(Depression)/sqrt(n())) %>%
      ggplot(data = .,                                               # change here 
           mapping = aes(x = Rumination, 
                         y = Depression,
                         color = Time,
                         ymin = avg_Depression - se_Depression,
                         ymax = avg_Depression + se_Depression)) +
                         geom_pointrange(size = 1.2, alpha = .6, 
                         position = position_dodge(width = .1)) +
           geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, se=F)+
           facet_wrap(~Group)+
           theme_bw() +
           theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. However, this time the x=rumination cannot be found in the dataset.